# problem in use C# to PHP Encryption code (github)

Tags: c#, php, cryptography

Due to the problem of using httpclient in my project, I had to convert the netframework version from .netframework 4.7 to .net6; I used C# to PHP Encryption in my project.
Now after converting my app is getting error.

my class :

```html
 public class RTPC
    {
        private X509Certificate2 cert;
        private bool initialized;

        public RTPC(string certificateLocation)
        {
            LoadCertificateFromFile(certificateLocation);
        }

        public RTPC()
        {
            initialized = false;
        }

        public void LoadCertificateFromFile(string certificateLocation)
        {
            try
            {
                cert = GetCertificateFromFile(certificateLocation);
                initialized = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                initialized = false;

                MessageBox.Show("Error in Loading Key ...", "Error");
                Environment.Exit(0);

            }

            if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in Loading Key ...", "Error");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

my function that have error :

```html
 public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] message)
        {
            if (initialized)
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider publicprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key ;
                return publicprovider.Encrypt(message, false);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in Loading Key ...", "Error");
                Environment.Exit(0);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

i get exception on this line :

```html
                RSACryptoServiceProvider publicprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key ;
```

exception is :
[image]

tnx all. plz help..

Answer (score 0):

i correct this problem by change this :

```html
 public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] message)
        {
            if (initialized)
            {          

                RSA csp = (RSA)cert.PublicKey.Key;
                byte[] bytesData = message;
              return  csp.Encrypt(bytesData, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in Loading Key ...", "Error");
                Environment.Exit(0);
                return null;
```

tnx every one and stackoverflow